# Uno platform: How to implement custom control on Webassembly

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

Having multi-target project in Uno Platform, I would like to create Wasm specific control (`HtmlView`). I have found some hints this is just `<div>` HTML content on Wasm and I should derive from `Control` and call `SetHtmlContent()`.

Unfortunately using the standard available references there is no `Control` (nor `FrameworkElement` - seen this in Uno documentation) having this method. Tried to add just a new class within Wasm head.

Am I supposed to reference some Uno specific *"Controls for Webassembly Library"* to derive from?

**EDIT:**
I guess [this](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/UIElement.wasm.cs) is the one I need. Unfortunately the project is not based on `Uno.UI`, but `Uno.WinUI`. Might this be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's not `Control` nor `FrameworkElement`, but it's `UIElement` and the `SetHtmlContent()` is extension method located in `Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElementWasmExtensions` class packaged in `Uno.WinUI.Runtime.WebAssembly` nuget.

The inheritance is then: `UIElement -> FrameworkElement -> Control`.